# React-select native select on mobile

Tags: reactjs, select, react-select

Is it possible to have [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) fall back to the native select on mobile devices?

And actually, why is that not the default behaviour?

Comment: The native html select is extremely limited in its options to be styled and adjusted. I would assume that the react-select library has choses not to do so that they could offer more flexible and wide-ranging features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't the responsibility of react-select, though if you need this behavior you can compose your own component to achieve it.

You'll need some sort of `isMobile()` check -- ["Detecting a mobile browser"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/2305750)

```
const MobileAwareSelect = (props) => isMobile() ? (
  <select>{props.options.map(...)}</select>
) : (
  <ReactSelect {...props} />
);
```

Answer (score 2):

blurInputOnSelect:

- boolean = isTouchCapable()
- Remove focus from the input when the user selects an option (handy for dismissing the keyboard on touch devices)